# Persistence Manager modifying object even closed?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, persistence, jetty, datanucleus

Recently I saw someone writes this piece of code, in which `Courses` is a static object, holding 1 `PersistenceManager` instance.

```
public class Courses {
    private PersistenceManager pm;

    private static Courses instance = null;

    public Courses() {
        pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    }

    public static Courses inst() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Courses();
        return instance;
    }

    public void addCourse(String ID, String name)  {
        Course course = new Course(ID, name, coordinatorID);
        pm.makePersistent(course);
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

This code works.

My question is, since there is only 1 persistence manager instance, when the second `addCourse` request coming in, isn't it the pm already closed? Why can it still persist the object?

I roughly know GAE uses Jetty Server. And unlike Apache, Jetty spawns a new thread per every request coming in. How does that fit into this picture?

Answer (score 1):

```
public Courses() {
    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
}
```

when you create a course it "re-creates" the pm.
so that you are able to use it.

```
public void addCourse(String ID, String name)  {
    Course course = new Course(ID, name, coordinatorID);
    pm.makePersistent(course);
    pm.close();
}
```